# How to recompile Laravel's Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel app running behind an Apache2/Ubuntu-16.04. I have to change a little code line in my controllers ( .i.e. a typo mistake in 
 `laravel_project/app/Http/Controller/MyController.php`). But when I reload the webpage using the browser, it still doesn't update with my fixed version. I tried some cleanup commands:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan list
php artisan clear-compiled
```

and also restart apache2 but it still doesn't work. Can you please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Use php artisan cache:clear

Comment: after the above command you also try php artisan serve command?

Comment: Can you please share your controller code

Comment: Other answers have suggested clearing your composer cache and auto load.

Comment: Check 'laravel.log' file. There must be log error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, its was because of routes cache

I resolved it by:

```
php artisan route:clear
```